# Is it valid to get the average of the corresponding elements of two time series?

Tags: time-series, aggregation

Say I have two time series that have the same length within the same time period. I need to replace the two time series with a single time series that explains the variations in both. So what I thought I could do was get the average of the corresponding elements and form the resulting time series.

For example, say the two time series represent the number of leaves taken by two individuals, and I want to check the leave patterns of the two individuals by a single time series. That is, I want to obtain the series that best represents both of their leave-taking patterns.

Is this procedure statistically valid? If not, what method should I use?

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "get a the replace" a pair of time series and what this operation is intended to represent?

Comment: Please note that I've edited the question. Hope now it's clear. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Thank you, but the edit doesn't seem to have cleared things up much: could you explain what you mean by a "resultant" time series?  In what sense do you mean "acceptable"?  What is this intended to be used for?

Comment: Please refer the edited question and comment whether it's understandable?

Comment: That helps, thank you -- but it's still not clear what you're trying to do.  Would it be possible to explain what these time series represent and what you mean by "explain variations"?  I'm not trying to give you a hard time, but I can't help thinking of examples where one time series might be related to the negative of the other (for instance, one of them charts the proportion of male live births and the other charts the proportion of female live births): in such cases, replacing them by their sum or average would destroy all the information you have!

Comment: No that's okay. I value your feedback. I've added an example, please refer to it

Comment: @AyeshaPerera Perhaps you could perform a PCA on your time series and use the projection of the original dataset on the first principle component as a "summarisation" of some sorts? Standard PCA does not exploit the temporal structure in your time series, though.

Comment: @Xiubo Zhang will the method that I have proposed be invalid?